# Clear a textbox when another is active (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML with two textboxes:

```
<input id="tb1" type="text" name="textbox1">
<input id="tb2" type="text" name="textbox2">
```

I want some JavaScript that will remove any content in textbox2 if the user has clicked/tabbed inside textbox1 (and vice versa).

I'm still learning JavaScript, but I think I need something like the following:

```
$('#textbox1').focus(function(){
    SOMETHING HERE TO CLEAR TEXTBOX2
});
```

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Have you tried `$('#tb2').value('');`? and should be `$('#tb1').focus();` instead

Comment: To expand on CodeLover's comment... You could keep an array of all of your textbox id's then when one is selected, you would make a copy of the original array, remove the currently selected one, then have `$(currentArrayItem).value('');`

Comment: A quick [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lts8drw1/) for you. You can add more inputs and it will function for those if you add a `class` name of `limit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your focus event is not working properly. The should use the hashtag sign and the element id (not the name).

```
$('#tb1').focus(function(){
    $('#tb2').val('');
});
```

Working pen:
https://codepen.io/Rechousa/pen/ddJXeq

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by binding the focus event on both inputs and then clearing the value of the one not focused. Ex:

```js
$('#tb1, #tb2').focus(function() {
  $('#tb1, #tb2').not(this).val('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tb1" type="text" name="textbox1">
<input id="tb2" type="text" name="textbox2">
```